# Removing horizontal black line in listings

Tags: listings

I'm using `listings` for code snippets and I can not seem to find a way to remove the horizontal line on the bottom of a `listings` environment.

My code:

```
\lstset{
        basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily, % Standardschrift
        numbers=left,               % Ort der Zeilennummern
        numberstyle=\color{blue!20!black!30!green}\tiny\ttfamily,          % Stil der Zeilennummern
        %stepnumber=2,               % Abstand zwischen den Zeilennummern
        numbersep=5pt,              % Abstand der Nummern zum Text
        tabsize=2,                  % Groesse von Tabs
        extendedchars=true,         %
        breaklines=true,            % Zeilen werden Umgebrochen
        keywordstyle=\color{red},
        frame=b,         
%        keywordstyle=[1]\textbf,    % Stil der Keywords
%        keywordstyle=[2]\textbf,    %
%        keywordstyle=[3]\textbf,    %
%        keywordstyle=[4]\textbf,   \sqrt{\sqrt{}} %
        stringstyle=\color{blue}\ttfamily, % Farbe der String
        showspaces=false,           % Leerzeichen anzeigen ?
        showtabs=false,             % Tabs anzeigen ?
        xleftmargin=0pt,
        framexleftmargin=0pt,
        framexrightmargin=0pt,
        framexbottommargin=4pt,
        %backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
        showstringspaces=false,      % Leerzeichen in Strings anzeigen ?  
        inputencoding=utf8,
          literate={å}{{\aa}}1
                        {æ}{{\ae}}1
                         {ø}{{\o}}1      
}
```

[image]

Comment: Without checking the documentation, I would guess that the line `frame=b` is the cause. (`b` for bottom.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT., did the trick!

Comment: @TorbjørnT. very good! Perhaps make this an answer, or let us close it as too localized since it was caused just by an accidental setting.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz, im quite new here, whats best-practice?

Comment: best-practice: providing an answer, as @TorbjørnT. did, if it's useful for other LaTeX users; closing as too localized if it's a small mistake or an issue which is very specific for just the questioner. And we remove the (not problem related) comments later, to keep the page clean and readable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is caused by the line

```
 frame=b
```

in `lstset`. As described in the manual, section **4.11 Frames**, `listings` can draw complete or partial frames around the listings, with single or double lines. `b` is for bottom, and draws a single line at the bottom of the listings.